# package which can only run in browser error in server-side-rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am using [**localForage**](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) in my SSR Nuxt project.

and in my `Nuxt-Page-Component`

```js
...
<script>
import localforage from 'localforage';
export default{
    mounted(){
        localforage.getItem('something', value => {
            ...
        });
    }
}
</script>
...
```

because the [**localforage**](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) can only work in browser, so I got an error like belows every time I try to visit the page in server-side-render mode
(althought the page can be rendered and the page works as what I want)

#### ERROR  No available storage method found. at node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js:2743:25

[image]

I try to use [**localforage**](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) as a custom plugin in my project which I config it as a client-side-only plugin

```js
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...    
    plugins:[
        { src: '~/plugins/localforage', ssr: false }
    ],
    ...
}

// localforage.js
import localforage from 'localforage';
window.localforage = localforage;

// localforage.js (or as a Vue plugin)
import localforage from 'localforage';
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use({
    install(Vue){
        Vue.prototype.$localforage = localforage;
    }
});
```

But I can only get more errors, and this time the page can't be rendered.

How can I fix this error, I already Google it, but it helps nothing.

Thanks a lot!

(not a native English specker, sorry for mistakes)

Comment: Why you dont out it in an if statement? `if(!process.server)`

Comment: how did you fixed, i didn't got that marked solution

Comment: @ManishPatidar Just follow the solution below will work. If you really care about seo, which you have to render the page in server side, do not use localforage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about lazy load module in the mounted?

```
<script>
export default{
    async mounted(){
        const localforage = await import('localforage')
        localforage.getItem('something', value => {
            ...
        });
    }
}
</script>
```