# Nuxt.js with vue-moment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, momentjs

I'm using vue-moment and it works perfectly, although i get an error in console

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: moment
```

What i'm doing:

```
plugins/moment.js

    import VueMoment from 'vue-moment'
    import Vue from 'vue'
    Vue.use(VueMoment)
```

---

```
nuxt.config.js

  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/moment.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
```

Vue-moment works just fine, but the error appears.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428780/package-which-can-only-run-in-browser-error-in-server-side-rendering) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pass on using Moment since it deprecated itself: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Rather using the module for `date-fns`, which is pretty simple to install and use: https://github.com/nuxt-community/date-fns-module

Answer (score 3):

try using the [Nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/moment) version.
It is specifically made for Nuxt so you won't have any issues.

Comment: Kindly note that vue-moment is different from moment. One is a filter, the other is the moment plugin.

Comment: @AntonyMN still not recommended tho.

Comment: @kissu I suppose this would work if you have legacy code you need to support. Going forward, use other packages

Comment: @AntonyMN if you can use moment.js, you could use pretty much anything else at this point. It's not like having a Node.js v8 dependency or alike. And if you have some legacy like this, moving to something else would be a priority tbh.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is still going through this, this was my approach.

In the plugins folder, I created a file named `vue-moment.js` and this is the content.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
```

After that, in the `nuxt.config.js` I added this line under `plugins`

```
plugins: [
...
"~/plugins/vue-moment",
...
],
```

Afterwards, when using it in the components, all I needed to do was call the function as shown below.

```
<span>{{ new Date() | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}</span>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: `filters` are deprecated in Vue2 because they are (already) removed in Vue3. Moment.js is old, not mantained anymore, not that flexible, mutable, heavy etc. So yeah, not a good recommended solution at all.